# Alguém sabe conectar o oracle no codeigniter?

Tags: php, codeigniter, oracle

Não estou conseguindo conectar o `codeigniter` no oracle.

Apresenta este erro:

```
A PHP Error was encountered
Severity: Notice
Message: Use of undefined constant OCI_COMMIT_ON_SUCCESS - assumed 'OCI_COMMIT_ON_SUCCESS'
Filename: database/DB.php
Line Number: 144
```

Database:

```
$db['default']['hostname'] = 'HOST:PORT/SID';
$db['default']['username'] = 'USER';
$db['default']['password'] = 'PASS';
$db['default']['database'] = '';
$db['default']['dbdriver'] = 'oci8';
$db['default']['dbprefix'] = '';
$db['default']['pconnect'] = FALSE;
$db['default']['db_debug'] = TRUE;
$db['default']['cache_on'] = FALSE;
$db['default']['cachedir'] = '';
$db['default']['char_set'] = 'utf8';
$db['default']['dbcollat'] = 'utf8_general_ci';
$db['default']['swap_pre'] = '';
$db['default']['autoinit'] = TRUE;
$db['default']['stricton'] = FALSE;
```

Modulo no apache habilitada:

```
extension=php_oci8.dll      
extension=php_oci8_11g.dll
```

O que pode ser?

Comment: O módulo está habilitado no `php.ini`?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/9877694/370290 - informações importantes nos *comments* - sua pergunta é idêntica a esta outra: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6758328/codeigniter-and-oracle-undefined-constant-oci-commit-on-success - a resposta de todas é a instalação do modo, verificar php.ini sendo usado, reiniciar Apache... de algum jeito **habilitar o módulo**, que apesar de você achar que está habilitado, ainda não está.

Comment: Resolvido!!!! Usuário deveria estar lowercase e estava em UPPERCASE!!!

Answer (score 2):

Após uma rápida pesquisa, tudo indica que a resposta só pode ser que, ao contrário do que foi afirmado na pergunta, **o módulo não está habilitado**. Resta saber então como fazer para efetivamente habilitá-lo.

- Você reiniciou o Apache após mudar as configurações?
- Verifique qual `php.ini` está sendo efetivamente utilizado. Pode ser que seja um arquivo diferente. (Por exemplo, o `php.ini` ativado pela linha de comando não é o mesmo `php.ini` ativado pelo navegador.)
- Verifique se não tem algum `.htaccess` ou equivalente modificando a configuração.

Comment: O modulo estava habilitado.
O problema foi com o usuario do banco de dados.